# SOAP cxf-codegen-plugin How to include a few schemas?

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I have a question. I need to generate classes from two schemas, that situated at `http://localhost:8080/Service/user?wsdl` and `http://localhost:8080/Service/role?wsdl`. but when I tried this:

```
<wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>http://localhost:8080/Service/user?wsdl</wsdl>
                                <wsdl>http://localhost:8080/Service/role?wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
```

It generates classes only for one of this links (for role service). Than I replace this link to another and it generates classes for other service. How to fix this? I need that plugin generate classes for both of this services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have two seperate wsdlOption elements inside the wsdlOptions element, one for each wsdl.